# Linear differential form not exact

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need explanation of the paragraphs with a vertical bar (extracted from Courant Intro to Analysis II):
[image]

I'm not sure why it's trying to justify that it makes sense in the first place if L is not 'exact'.  And then I'm confused as to why after using the curve C, L is not exact, when it seems to say that L becomes the differential of that integral - I may have just misinterpreted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old-fashioned discussion. All that Courant is saying is that you can integrate *any* differential $1$-form $\omega = A\,dx + B\,dy + C\,dz$ along a parametrized path $C$ (given by $\big(x(t),y(t),z(t)\big)$, $a\le t\le b$) by calculating
$$\int_C\omega = \int_a^b \big(A(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dx}{dt} + B(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dy}{dt} + C(x(t),y(t),z(t))\frac{dz}{dt}\big)dt.$$
The chain rule will tell you that, in fact, the value is independent of how you parametrize $C$.

Comment: Ok but then why does he say the expression "L" is not integrable when it in fact is?

Comment: By "integrable" he means that you can find a potential function $f$ so that $df = L$ (that's what an exact differential is). That's equivalent to having the line integral I wrote down be path-independent. As I say, this is somewhat of a dated text to be reading. You might try looking at my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile).

Comment: I have a small issue with the statement about line integral being independent of parametrization.  The proof seems to be assume that $u=f(t)$ is differentiable, but is that really necessary?  Courant in the same book seems to suggest continuous monotone function is all that required.  I can ask this question in new post if you like.

Comment: You can generalize to Lebesgue integrals, of course, but ordinarily we're interested in $C^k$ (or $C^\infty$) manifolds and $C^k$ (with $k\ge 2$) forms.

Comment: I'm unclear about your answer because I'm not up to Lebesgue integrals.  All I really wanted to know is that if we try to use a new parameter $u$ instead of $t$, with $u=f(t)$ does $f$ have to be differentiable for the line integral over that curve be the same for both parametrizations?.

In fact by using the definition of line integral as the limit of a rienmann sum based on points rather than any parameter courant says immediately that the integral is independent of parameter.

Comment: To define a line integral, unless you're working in a fancy setting, you need $C^1$ functions. You at least need to know that $Ax'+By'+Cz'$ is integrable, so you need differentiable functions $x,y,z$ with a bit more hypothesis. I believe your last comment is about an integral of the form $\int_C f\,ds$ rather than for the integral of a $1$-form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91532/discussion-between-helios321-and-ted-shifrin).